# How to get all cache key and values with cache manager in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

Hi i want to find all keys and values in my cache.

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("users");
```

I just have cache name that is "users" and i can get cache with this name but i want to see my all cache keys and values how to get this.
I just want to find this with cache name, i have no cache key.

Comment: not fimillar with spring boot cache (I'm using Hazelcast) but can't you iterate on cache.getNativeCache() ? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829383/how-to-iterate-on-a-cache-entries

Comment: I looked your solition but it's not working for me

    Cache cache = (Cache) cacheManager.getCache("yourCacheName").getNativeCache();
    Iterator<Cache.Entry> iterator = cache.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next().getKey();
        System.out.println(key);
    } 

when i try the this solution iterator() method is not coming for me

Comment: What cache implementation are you using? You can find out with: .getNativeCache().getClass(). If its Guava or Caffeine you need to use the map view, for example: `getNativeCache().asMap().entrySet()`

Comment: I'am using rediscache but ı dont want to specific solution to redis. I want to make cache ui to see cache names and values in application. So i need generic solution, is it possible?

Comment: The Spring cach abstraction does not support this. One possibility is switching to JCache/JSR107. JCache is an API supported by many cache vendors, which also defines an iterator.